# Segment Tree Kth Maximum

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree

Hi I was solving the problem on a segment tree,But I am not able to make a little modification to the query function of segment tree .

Actually What I want is my query function should return the (int)(TotalArrayLength/3) th maximum  element between index Qa and Qb.

The Query Function that I wrote Returns the Maximum element between index[1-based] a_begin and a_end.

But I want to return the (int)(TotalArrayLength/3)th Maximum element between index[1-based] a_begin and a_end.

```
    int query(int Nodenumber,int t_begin,int t_end,int a_begin,int a_end)
    {
        if (t_begin>=a_begin && t_end<=a_end)
            return Tree[Nodenumber];
        else
        {
            int mid=((t_begin+t_end)/2);
            int res = -1;

            if (mid>=a_begin && t_begin<=a_end)
                res = max(res,query(2*Nodenumber,t_begin,mid,a_begin,a_end));

            if (t_end>=a_begin && mid+1<=a_end)
                res = max(res,query(2*Nodenumber+1,mid+1,t_end,a_begin,a_end));

            return res;
        }
    }
```

Note to make a query  ,I call the query function as query(1,0,N-1,QA,QB).

Also I implemented the [following](http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Segment_tree#Maximum.2Fminimum_prefix.2Fsuffix_sum) Pseudo-code to write above query Function,

So How should I modify to find  (int)(TotalArrayLength/3)th Maximum element between index[1-based] a_begin and a_end.

Basically ,the problem I am solving is :

Initially the array contains 0 or more element. Randomly some data is to be inserted at the end of the array and at any time a query is to be done that return TotalArraySize/3 th Max Elements in Array build so far.

Also ,did I select the right data structure for the purpose.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first though is:

You'll need to use a K sized sorted list as a return value for each query() call. If the query lies fully to the left or the right of the mid-point then return that result. If the query straddles the mid point then merge the result of each child when they return. Once you get back to the root then you return the kth element in the resulting sorted list.

The method signature (in Java) would be:

```
List<Integer> query(int Nodenumber,int t_begin,int t_end,int a_begin,int a_end)
```

A max heap data structure could accomplish the same job. Just build the max-heap from the items between the indices and pop off the head k times.

A segment tree would be good at multiple queries where a heap would be better in terms of overall memory and single queries on the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot Justin ..But Java is not my poor language ,how can i accomplish it in C/C++

Comment: I don't know C++ that well but _any_ sorted list structure should work. Basically, instead of each Node containing a single int the way it would in a max sub-vector segment tree; each node would contain a  list of each element in it's sub-tree sorted by value. Something like a list<int> which is sorted once all elements are added.

Comment: @Jack I've re-worded my answer a bit to handle cases when the query lies to either side of the mid-point OR when the query straddles the mid-point.

Comment: What will be the overall complexity... ? I have to make 10^5 operations(Insertions/update +  querying Kth Max) ,and say the time limit is 2 -3 seconds,will it work,because I can see your approach uses the sorting on every query.

Comment: @Jack I'm not sure the exact complexity. Segment tree's are designed for slow construction and very fast queries. The tree I described should _not_ use sorting on every query. It uses sorting on construction, insertion, and updating. The only time it'll use sorting on a query is if the queried indices lie across the mid-point of a segment. Even when that happens, you'll be merging two sorted lists which is fairly fast with an appropriate (insertion sort) sorting algorithm.

Comment: @Jack my guess about the complexity is: insert/update is O(log log(n)) which means construction is O(n log log(n)). Query is either O(log(n)) for non-straddling and O(log log(n)) for straddling.